# REST endpoint registration and bootstrap(Creating range-index) using U Deploy

Tags: rest, xquery, devops, marklogic-9, udeploy

I have my code in Git repository. I am using UDeploy to deploy my code into MarkLogic environment. I can able to move all my modules successfully but facing two problems
  1. Creating New indexes 
  2. REST endpoint creation
Please let me know if there is anyway to implement these two

For creating indexes, I have tried to do it using API functions(admin:database-range-element-index()) and I have successful in that part. But is there any way to do it from UDeploy or DevOps.
For register REST endpoint I couldn't able to find anyway to try.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at MarkLogic's REST Management APIs - https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/management. In particular, see if https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/manage/v2/databases will help you create indexes via REST management APIs.

Answer (score 2):

The most common way to deploy MarkLogic code & configuration is [ml-gradle](https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle), a plugin to the widely used gradle tool. ml-gradle uses MarkLogic's Management API, mentioned by Ganesh, and is scriptable.

Comment: I don't know UDeploy nor DevOps, but if you can run a command line script, ml-gradle could be simplest. Otherwise invoking the REST APIs might be more straight-forward. If invoking Java code would be an option, [ml-app-deployer](https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-app-deployer) (the engine behind ml-gradle) might be of interest as well..